# Цикл в цикле в цикле

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток, господа. PHP код:

```
// работает
$i = 10;
while ($w < $i)
{
    $a = $w + 1;
    echo $w;
}

// не работает 8-)
$i = 10;
while ($w < $i)
{
    $a = $w + 1;
    echo $w;

    while ($b < $i)
    {
        $b = $b + 1;
        echo $b;

        while ($r < $i)
        {
            $r = $r + 1;
            echo $r;
        }
    }
}
```

Интересует простое, запихать цикл в цикл в цикл while (не for не do while). подскажите, как так сделать.

p.s. обновил буквы на латыницу

Comment: Может дело в том, что переменные $a, $b, $c не инициализированы?

Comment: А вообще, в будущем при отладке используйте error_reporting(E_ALL), чтобы точно знать, в каком месте ошибка.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. переменные могут называться тока латинскими буквами. Не русскими. Я про $c.
2. будет ругань по поводу неинициализированных $a,$b,$c. Их желательно обнулять.
3. после исправления 1 и 2 имеем ожидаемый резалт: 111234567891023456789102345678910

Comment: Ох уж эти "c" и "с" :)

Comment: а ОНО, главное, даже их подсветило: сравниваем желтые $c и черные $a, $b

Comment: > переменные могут называться тока латинскими буквами. Не русскими. Я про $c.

Переменные могут иметь *любые* юникодные имена (в т.ч. и русскими), если php собран с опцией [`--enable-zend-multibyte`](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php#configure.enable-zend-multibyte) (включена по умолчанию в большинстве дитрибутивов)

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, плюсую, в т.ч. в некоторых обфускаторах применяют наборы непечатаемых символов) Выглядит примерно так

    $     = ($) -     ($,$,$    ,$+1);

Comment: <a rel="nofollow" href="/users/1797/ilya-pirogov">@Ilya Pirogov</a>, а как оно тогда отличит $$a, где имя переменной '$a' или где имя переменной $a?

Comment: @knes, очевидно, что никак не отличит. И не должен отличать. Тем не менее имя переменной может быть любой, в т.ч. и '$a':

    ${'$a'} = 1;
    $var = '$a';

    var_dump($GLOBALS);
    // array(...) {
    //   ...
    //   ["$a"]=> 
    //   int(1)
    // }

    var_dump($$var);
    // int(1)

Answer (score 5):

Переменные надо не только **инициализировать** но и **обнулять** заново перед каждым стартом цикла.

```
$a =0; // тут
while ($a < $i)
{
    // что угодно

    $b = 0; // тут
    while ($b < $i)
    {
        // что угодно

        $c = 0; // тут
        while ($c < $i)
        {
            // что угодно
        }
    }
}
```

Переменные могут быть названы и с использованием кириллицы. Лишь бы не путались.

Comment: спасибо. получилось

Answer (score 0):

### Заголовок

[[@xEdelweiss](/users/7017/xedelweiss)](/users/7017/xedelweiss): Главное не забыть объявить $i, а то будет бесконечный цикл...

```
// работает
$i = 10;
while ($w < $i)
{
    $a = $w + 1;
    echo $w;
}
```

Здесь явно ошибка в том, что Вы изменяете значение $a, в то же время, $w остаётся всё таким же и вы получаете бесконечный цикл... если же так, то стоит, наверно, указывать '

```
    $i = 10;
    while ($a < $i)
    {
        $a = $a + 1;
        echo $a;
    }
```

В последующем примере у Вас остаётся всё та же ошибка. 
Вам либо нужно в условии писать $a<$i , либо, уже в последствии, изменить следующее:

```
$a = $w + 1;
```

на

```
$w = $w + 1;
```

и то, что говорил xEdelweiss

Comment: $a на $w автор изменил, непонимаю зачем, только в 3й редакции вопроса. На данный момент, замечание действительно ценное. 
Про $i - само собой. Акцент был именно на обнулении переменных.

Comment: заменил, так же как и c->r, чтобы точно было понятно русский это символ или латинский. Ваш К.О.
Только он это сделал весьма своеобразно: частично. =)